# How do I collect more information from a user after authenticating externally?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-authentication

I'm using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` package. If I allow a user to authenticate with Google, where is the place that I should inject my own form to collect some more information that Google would not have access to (a custom identifier for example).

1. Should I present a form, collect the data up front and store it in session or something while they go off to authorize the login?
2. Should I let them go authorize the login, then when the callback URL is invoked, present the form there?

There are four events exposed via the middleware:

1. `OnTicketReceived`
2. `OnCreatingTicket`
3. `OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint`
4. `OnRemoteFailure`

Is there an example anywhere that this is being done? I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it with Cookie middleware. I added 'temp' cookie middleware to catch the ClaimsPrincipal from logging in to Google and then I sign in to the 'real' Cookie middleware to persist the enriched ClaimsPrincipal. The relevant piece of code in the Configure method of the StartUp class:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString(@"/account/login"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(@"/account/accessdenied")
        });

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Temp",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false
        });

    var googleOptions = new GoogleOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
        SignInScheme = "Temp",
        AppId = "yourappidhere",
        AppSecret = "yourappsecrethere"
    };
    googleOptions.Scope.Add("scopesyouneed");

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

Note how the SignInScheme of the googleOptions is "Temp" and the options of the 'temp' Cookie middleware has it's AutomaticAuthenticate to false (because you don't want to automatically persist the ClaimsPrinciple in the temp Cookie, but enriched and all in the real one which is called "Cookie" here).

Then the relevant methods in my controller look like:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var externalPrincipal = await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Temp");

    //TODO Check external principal and retrieve claims from db or whatever needs to be done here.

    var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim("email", externalPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value)
        };
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "password");
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Temp");

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> LogInGoogle(string returnUrl = null)
{
    var queryString = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) ? $"?returnUrl={returnUrl}" : string.Empty;
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = $@"Account/Register{queryString}" }; //new PathString(returnUrl)

    return await Task.Run<ChallengeResult>(() => new ChallengeResult("Google", props));

}
```

Note how LoginGoogle is called via a link on your page or something. Remember how GoogleMiddleware's SignInScheme is "Temp" at this point. It's redirected to the "Register" action method. There you extract the ClaimsPrinciple from Google with the code:

var externalPrincipal = await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Temp");

At this point you can do whatever you need to do with the claims. I extract the e-mail claim as you can see. And I sign in with my "Cookie" sign in scheme, to persist the ClaimsPrinciple in a cookie. But you could also redirect to the view with the form with which you request more information from the user.